# Unable to unmarshall the CXF response payload

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, jetty, cxf

I had to update the versions to *camel-core-2.16.0* & *CXF-core-3.1.3.jar* from *camel-core-2.15.3* & *CXF-core-3.0.6.jar*, to avoid the problem similar to this *[Apache Camel - Receiving SOAP response with empty body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409667/apache-camel-receiving-soap-response-with-empty-body)*,which has resolved the purpose of my search.

But now even though I get the response body correctly, in my logs I am getting an unmarshall exception,which I wasn't facing when I used the previous versions of jars.

here is the code snippet which gives the exception:

```
    public static Object getPojoFromCXFPayload(CxfPayload payload, Class pojoClass) throws Exception {
    List<Source> outElements = payload.getBodySources();
    XmlConverter converter = new XmlConverter();
    DOMSource domsource = null;
    Object pojo = null;
    if (outElements != null && outElements.size() > 0) {
        if(DEBUG)
            logger.debug("outElements size is " + outElements.size());
        domsource = converter.toDOMSource(outElements.get(0));
        //JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(pojoClass);
        JAXBContext context = JaxContextInitilizer.getContext();
        Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();

        if (domsource.getNode().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if(DEBUG){
                logger.debug("This is element node");
            }
        } else if (domsource.getNode().getNodeType() == Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            if(DEBUG){
                logger.debug("this is document node");
            }
            ((Document) domsource.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
            if(DEBUG){
                logger.debug(((Document) domsource.getNode()).getDocumentElement());
            }
        }

        pojo = m.unmarshal(domsource.getNode()); //I could see the exception pointing to this line
    }

    return pojo;
}
```

Comment: can you please add the stack trace here....

Comment: @sarav did u find any solution of it.?

Comment: camel version 2.15.3 helped us resolve this.